# Deep learning to classify a time series of xy spatial coordinates - python

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I've got a few problems with a DL classification problem. I'll attach a brief example of the training data to help describe the problem.

The data is a time series of xy points, which is made up of smaller   sub-sequences `event`. So each unique `event` is independent. I have two unique sequences `(10,20)` below of even time length. For a given sequence, each individual point has its own unique identifier `user_id`. The xy trace of these points will vary marginally over a given sequence, with the specific time period found in `interval`. I also have a separate xy point used as a reference `(centre_x, center_y)`, which details the approx middle/centre of all points.

Lastly, the `target_label` classifies where these points are relative to each other. So using the `centre_x, center_y` as a reference, there are 5 class **Middle, Top, Bottom, Right, Left**. There can only be one label for each unique `event`.

**Problems:**

1. Obviously small dataset but I'm concerned with the accuracy accuracy. I think I need to incorporate the reference point `(centre_x, center_y)`
2. I'm getting all these warning for each test iteration. I think it has something to do with converting to a tensor but it doesn't;t help anything.

   WARNING:tensorflow:7 out of the last 7 calls to <function Model.make_test_function..test_function at 0x7faa21629820> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.

example df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# number of intervals
n = 10

# center locations for points
locs_1 = {'A': (5,5),
      'B': (5,8),
      'C': (5,2),
      'D': (8,5)}

# initialize data 
data_1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(n*len(locs_1)), columns=['x','y','user_id'])
for i, group in enumerate(locs_1.keys()):

    data_1.loc[i*n:((i+1)*n)-1,['x','y']] = np.random.normal(locs_1[group], 
                                                       [0.2,0.2], 
                                                       [n,2]) 
    data_1.loc[i*n:((i+1)*n)-1,['user_id']] = group

# generate time interavls
data_1['interval'] = data_1.groupby('user_id').cumcount() + 1

# assign unique string to differentiate sequences
data_1['event'] = 10

# center of all points for unqiue sequence 1
data_1['center_x'] = 5
data_1['center_y'] = 5

# classify labels
data_1['target_label'] = ['Middle' if ele  == 'A' else 'Top' if ele == 'B' else 'Bottom' if ele == 'C' else 'Right' for ele in data_1['user_id']]

# center locations for points
locs_2 = {'A': (14,15),
      'B': (16,15),
      'C': (15,12),
      'D': (19,15)}

# initialize data 
data_2 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(n*len(locs_2)), columns=['x','y','user_id'])
for i, group in enumerate(locs_2.keys()):

    data_2.loc[i*n:((i+1)*n)-1,['x','y']] = np.random.normal(locs_2[group], 
                                                       [0.2,0.2], 
                                                       [n,2]) 
    data_2.loc[i*n:((i+1)*n)-1,['user_id']] = group

# generate time interavls
data_2['interval'] = data_2.groupby('user_id').cumcount() + 1

# center of points for unqiue sequence 1
data_2['event'] = 20

# center of all points for unqiue sequence 2
data_2['center_x'] = 15
data_2['center_y'] = 15

# classify labels
data_2['target_label'] = ['Middle' if ele  == 'A' else 'Middle' if ele == 'B' else 'Bottom' if ele == 'C' else 'Right' for ele in data_2['user_id']]

df = pd.concat([data_1, data_2])

df = df.sort_values(by = ['event','interval','user_id']).reset_index(drop = True)
```

df:

```
            x          y user_id  interval  event  center_x  center_y target_label
0    5.288275   5.211246       A         1     10         5         5       Middle
1    4.765987   8.200895       B         1     10         5         5          Top
2    4.943518   1.645249       C         1     10         5         5       Bottom
3    7.930763   4.965233       D         1     10         5         5        Right
4    4.866746   4.980674       A         2     10         5         5       Middle
..        ...        ...     ...       ...    ...       ...       ...          ...
75  18.929254  15.297437       D         9     20        15        15        Right
76  13.701538  15.049276       A        10     20        15        15       Middle
77  16.028816  14.985672       B        10     20        15        15       Middle
78  15.044336  11.631358       C        10     20        15        15       Bottom
79   18.95508  15.217064       D        10     20        15        15        Right
```

Model:

```
labels = df['target_label'].dropna().sort_values().unique()

n_samples = df.groupby(['user_id', 'event']).ngroups
n_ints = 10

X = df[['x','y']].values.reshape(n_samples, n_ints, 2).astype('float32')

y = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['event','user_id','target_label'])

y = np.array(y['target_label'].groupby(level = 0).apply(lambda x: [x.values[0]]).tolist())

y = label_binarize(y, classes = labels)

# test, train split
trainX, testX, trainy, testy = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

# load the dataset, returns train and test X and y elements
def load_dataset():

    # test, train split
    trainX, testX, trainy, testy = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

    return trainX, trainy, testX, testy

# fit and evaluate a model
def evaluate_model(trainX, trainy, testX, testy):
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10, 32
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2], trainy.shape[1]
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # fit network
    model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    # evaluate model
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    return accuracy

# summarize scores
def summarize_results(scores):
    print(scores)
    m, s = np.mean(scores), np.std(scores)
    print('Accuracy: %.3f%% (+/-%.3f)' % (m, s))

# run an experiment
def run_experiment(repeats=10):
    # load data
    trainX, trainy, testX, testy = load_dataset()
    # repeat experiment
    scores = list()
    for r in range(repeats):
        #r = tf.convert_to_tensor(r, dtype=tf.int32)
        score = evaluate_model(trainX, trainy, testX, testy)
        score = score * 100.0
        print('>#%d: %.3f' % (r+1, score))
        scores.append(score)
    # summarize results
    summarize_results(scores)

# run the experiment
run_experiment()
```

Comment: I'm not asking for code. I'm asking for directions or sources to examples. After trawling through various sites for days I can't find anything that uses xy coordinate data. It's like you didn't even read the content. I have stated the intended purpose of the question twice but I'll put it in bold and caps.

Comment: Is your mean of _raw data_ only x and y columns? or all columns except target? You can use all of architectures and layers as you want. You may try them and see which one them is more suited to your problem. However, if it is a sequence, it is better to use LSTM, RNN, GRU layers and even combination with Conv1D and Dense layers. But what do you exactly want? Have you tried any model and you are not satisfied with them? and you want to improve accuracy? I think it will be good if you share at least a sample of your data and a reproducible code, so we will be able to amend your code for you.

Comment: The example data frame is all the info I'll have in my training dataset. I'll have the same for the test dataset (except target_label). I understand your point but I can't find any examples with xy coordinate data as a single input variable. Or would you treat them as separate variables?

Comment: Yes exactly. They are separate variables. Let's take you have 5 variables input (5 features) and 1 output. Therefore your input data shape should be something like (100,5) which means you have 100 samples and each of them has 5 features and the output shape will be (100,) which means you have 1 label (1 number) corresponding to each input. And if you want to use timeseries or sequences (say each sample has 10 timesteps), then the input shape should be like (100,10,5) and the output (100,). The second dimension of your train data should be the timestep.

Comment: The warnings seem to be about possible runtime optimizations and not to affect the results.

Comment: How many time series does your dataset have? Do you get bad predictions on the test set, or also on the training set?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do time series classification using 2d time series of length 10. It seems like you only have a handfull examples per class which is way too little to do any training of neural networks on. Even if you would have a hunderd examples, I would recommend going for a method that is able to work with less data. One example would be using K-nearest neighbours using a time series specific distance metric like Dynamic Time Warping for example.